# Extract divs with at least one class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup

Supose you have a web page with a lot of this:

```
<div class="story cid-8797378263432 l-es headline-story thumbnail-true">
```

where cid-nnnnnnnnnnnn class can vary. How would you get all the divs with BeautifulSoup?

I tried:

```
soup.find('div', {'class': 'story'})
```

but that didn't work. Seems to look for the divs with ONLY the story class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242755/beautiful-soup-cannot-find-a-css-class-if-the-object-has-other-classes-too/1242801#1242801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug: [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/410304). The report also contains a workaround:

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class': re.compile(r'\bstory\b')})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use `soup.findAll('div', 'story')` which doesn't seem to have that bug.