# Python - BeautifulSoup - HTML Parsing

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Here is fragment of the site code

```
<td class='vcard' id='results100212571'>   
 <h2 class="custom_seeMore">
  <a class="fn openPreview" href="link.html">Hotel Name<span class="seeMore">See More...</span></a>
 </h2> 
 <div class='clearer'></div> 
 <div class='adr'>
  <span class='postal-code'>00000</span> 
  <span class='locality'>City</span> 
  <span class='street-address'>Address</span>
 </div>
 <p class="tel">Phone number</p>
```

and I try to parse it

```
for element in BeautifulSoup(page).findAll('td'):
    if element.find('a', {'class' : 'fn openPreview'}):
        print element.find('a', {'class' : 'fn openPreview'}).string
    if element.find('span', {'class' : 'postal-code'}):
        print element.find('span', {'class' : 'postal-code'}).string
    if element.find('span', {'class' : 'locality'}):
        print element.find('span', {'class' : 'locality'}).string
    if element.find('span', {'class' : 'street-address'}):
        print element.find('span', {'class' : 'street-address'}).string
    if element.find('p', {'class' : 'tel'}):
        print element.find('p', {'class' : 'tel'}).string
```

I know it's very amateur code, but it almost works. ie it works for all classes except 'fn openPreview', all other classes draw their content, but

```
print element.find('a', {'class' : 'fn openPreview'}).string
```

print None

Please help me, how to parse it.

Comment: Maybe because fn and openPreview are separate classes. An element can have multiple space separated classes.

Comment: Oddly enough, it looks like BeautifulSoup treats `fn openPreview` as a single class.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242755/beautiful-soup-cannot-find-a-css-class-if-the-object-has-other-classes-too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to the BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#string), `element.string` will be `None` if `element` has multiple children.

In your case,

```
print element.find('a', {'class' : 'fn openPreview'}).contents[0].string
```

will print "Hotel Name".