# BeautifulSoup and Searching By Class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beautiful Soup cannot find a CSS class if the object has other classes, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242755/beautiful-soup-cannot-find-a-css-class-if-the-object-has-other-classes-too)

I'm using BeautifulSoup to find `tables` in the HTML. The problem I am currently running into is the use of spaces in the `class` attribute. If my HTML reads `<html><table class="wikitable sortable">blah</table></html>`, I can't seem to extract it with the following (where I was to be able to find `tables` with both `wikipedia` and `wikipedia sortable` for the `class`):

```
BeautifulSoup(html).findAll(attrs={'class':re.compile("wikitable( sortable)?")})
```

This will find the table if my HTML is just `<html><table class="wikitable">blah</table></html>` though. Likewise, I have tried using `"wikitable sortable"` in my regular expression, and that won't match either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The pattern match will also fail if `wikitable` appears after another CSS class, as in `class="something wikitable other"`, so if you want all tables whose class attribute contains the class `wikitable`, you need a pattern that accepts more possibilities:

```
html = '''<html><table class="sortable wikitable other">blah</table>
<table class="wikitable sortable">blah</table>
<table class="wikitable"><blah></table></html>'''

tree = BeautifulSoup(html)
for node in tree.findAll(attrs={'class': re.compile(r".*\bwikitable\b.*")}):
    print node
```

Result:

```
<table class="sortable wikitable other">blah</table>
<table class="wikitable sortable">blah</table>
<table class="wikitable"><blah></blah></table>
```

---

Just for the record, I don't use BeautifulSoup, and prefer to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), as others have mentioned.

Comment: Just as an update, the latest version of BeautifulSoup (bs4) handles this much more elegantly: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Answer (score 8):

One of the things that makes [**lxml**](http://lxml.de) better than BeautifulSoup is support for proper CSS-like class selection (or even supports [full css selectors](http://lxml.de/dev/cssselect.html) if you want to use them)

```
import lxml.html

html = """<html>
<body>
<div class="bread butter"></div>
<div class="bread"></div>
</body>
</html>"""

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

elements = tree.find_class("bread")

for element in elements:
    print lxml.html.tostring(element)
```

Gives:

```
<div class="bread butter"></div>
<div class="bread"></div>
```

Comment: +1 Even though this doesn't help @allie write BeautifulSoup code, lxml is far superior.

Comment: While I appreciate the elegance of that, BeautifulSoup is what is already here, and for the time being, that's what I need to use. :)

Comment: The reason so many people prefer BS for html and lxml for XML is because it (BS) is far more tollerant of broken html.  lxml doesn't handle broken html well.