# Can you search by classname in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In BeautifulSoup you can search by using soup.find_all. For example I searched a page by using

```
soup.find_all("tr", "cat-list-row1")
```

That, obviously, brought every tr class that had the name cat-list-row1. I was wanting to know if it is possible to search the whole page for any class that is named "cat-list-row1" instead of limiting it to just classes where the element is "tr".

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890659/beautifulsoup-and-searching-by-class

Comment: Try `soup.select('.cat-list-row1')` for all elements with that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Multiple ways](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

- using a `class_` argument (`class` cannot be used, it is a reserved keyword in Python):

  ```
  soup.find_all(class_="cat-list-row1")
  ```
- use `attrs` dictionary

  ```
  soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "cat-list-row1"})
  ```
- use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

  ```
  soup.select('.cat-list-row1')
  ```

Note that `BeautifulSoup` handles multiple classes easily applying the "Multi-valued attributes" concept:

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its “class”
>   attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class,
>   you’re matching against any of its CSS classes.

Comment: What if there were multiple classnames for "cat-list-row1" on the page that did not have the "tr" element? Is there a way I could just search for "cat-list-row1"?

Comment: @Scott please see the update and the appropriate [documentation page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class). Should clear things up.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I was able to accomplish it with your help.