# beautifulsoup doesn't fully parse the page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url1 = 'https://school.karelia.ru/auth/login'
url2 = 'https://school.karelia.ru/personal-area/#diary'

payload = {
    'login_login': 'КлочковМ',
    'login_password': 'КлочковМ7'
}

def getHW():
    with requests.session() as s:
        s.post(url1, data=payload)
        r = s.get(url2)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.find_all("div"))

getHW()
```

i am trying to parse a site, and this code just doesnt do it fully. in the website's code, there are a lot more subclasses than the result i get from this code:

```
<div class="right" id="main-region"></div>
```

for some reason, the class "right" just ends there, even though in the site it continues a lot more. why could this be?

Comment: The site probably uses Javascript to fully render the page. I suggest you try *selenium*

Answer (score 1):

it is because you did `soup.find_all("div")`. the div ends there with `</div>` and you told BS to only look for divs, so BS stops there.
to actually search for classes see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890659/beautifulsoup-and-searching-by-class#5890756)