# How to Beautiful Soup (bs4) match just one, and only one, css class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using following code to match all div that have CSS class "ad_item".

```
soup.find_all('div',class_="ad_item")
```

problem that I have is that, on that web page, there are also div that have CSS class set to "ad_ex_item" and "ad_ex_item".

```
<div class="ad_item ad_ex_item">
```

[In documentation it is stated:](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

> When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re
>   matching against any of its CSS classes:

So how can I match div, that have only "ad_item", and do not have "ad_ex_item".

Or to put this in another way, how to search for div that have only CSS class "ad_item" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242755/beautiful-soup-cannot-find-a-css-class-if-the-object-has-other-classes-too?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found one solution, although it have nothing to do with BS4, it is pure python code.

```
for item in soup.find_all('div',class_="ad_item"):
     if len(item["class"]) != 1:
         continue;
```

It basically skip item, if there is more than one CSS class.

Answer (score 10):

You can use strict conditions like this:

```
soup.select("div[class='ad_item']")
```

That catch `div` with exact class.
In this case with only `'ad_item'` and no others joined by spaces classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a lambda functions to `find` and `find_all` methods.

```
soup.find_all(lambda x:
    x.name == 'div' and
    'ad_item' in x.get('class', []) and
    not 'ad_ex_item' in x['class']
)
```

The `x.get('class', [])` will avoid `KeyError` exceptions for `div` tags without `class` attribute.

If you need to exclude more than only one class you can substitute the last condition with:

```
    not any(c in x['class'] for c in {'ad_ex_item', 'another_class'})
```

And if you want to exclude exactly some classes you can use:

```
   not all(c in x['class'] for c in {'ad_ex_item', 'another_class'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `select` : http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

```
soup.select(".add_item")
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `:not` selector of CSS3 is not supported. If you really need this, you may have to look at [lxml](http://lxml.de). It seems to support it. see http://packages.python.org/cssselect/#supported-selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can always [write a Python function that matches the tag you want](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function), and pass that function into find_all():

```
def match(tag):
    return (
        tag.name == 'div'
        and 'ad_item' in tag.get('class')
        and 'ad_ex_item' not in tag.get('class'))

soup.find_all(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is correct but if you want a way to keep the for loop clean or like one line solutions then use the list comprehension below.

```
data = [item for item in soup.find_all("div", class_="ad_item") if len(item["class"]) == 1]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
soup.fetch('div',{'class':'add_item'})
```

Comment: I am using Beautiful Soup 4, BS4 does not have fetch.