# I want to get the value of multiple ids inside an a tag that resides in a div

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="sizeBlock">
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44526" data-size-original="36.5">36.5</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size inactive active"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44524" data-size-original="40">40</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size "> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44525" data-size-original="40.5">40.5</a> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

I want to get the values of the id tag and the data-size-original.

Here's my code:

```
for sizeBlock in soup.find_all('a', class_="selectSize"):
        aid  = sizeBlock.get('id')
        size = sizeBlock.get('data-size-us')
```

The problem is that it gets the values of other ids that have the same class "selectSize".

Comment: So along with the required you also get other id's. This is the issue ?

Your code is written for that purpose, you are iterating over all <a> elements which have class="selectSize" and getting their id's.

If you have multiple elements with same class size, you will get the last element's id as your result.

Comment: Please post the actual HTML (not an image) you want to parse.

Comment: @Florian - You can edit your question to include this information. This saves time for everyone, you would not have to comment on each and every post and people can easily debug your code if it is presented properly.

Comment: give the code that produces your issue. The snippit you provided doesn't show "The problem is that it gets the values of other ids that have the same class "selectSize"". Also there is no 'data-size-us' attribute in your example

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. You won't have ids and size from data in div class='size inactive active'

```
for sizeBlock in soup.select('div.size a.selectSize'):
    aid = sizeBlock.get('id')
    size = sizeBlock.get('data-size-us')
```

Comment: Just ran the code and it returns `id="44524"` found in `<div class="size inactive active">`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here [How to Beautiful Soup (bs4) match just one, and only one, css class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496860/how-to-beautiful-soup-bs4-match-just-one-and-only-one-css-class)

Use `soup.select`. Here's a simple test:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="size">
<a class="selectSize otherclass" id="44526" data-ean="0193394075362" " data-tprice="" data-sku="1171177-36.5" data-size-original="36.5">5</a>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

#for sizeBlock in soup.find_all('a', class_= "selectSize"): # this would include the anchor
for sizeBlock in soup.select("a[class='selectSize']"):
    aid = sizeBlock.get('id')
    size = sizeBlock.get('data-size-original')
    print aid, size
```

Comment: This actaully would include ids and sizes form <div class="size inactive active"><a class="selectSize"></div> too, which I don't need. I only need data from <div class="size"><a class="selectSize"></div>. I think this happens because of the word "size" in both <a>s. I was thinking of decomposing that element but couldn't get it work.