# Finding exact match with regex (python) does not work

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup

I am browsing through HTML scripts with BeautifulSoup4 and I am trying to find an exact match of a tag.
I tried this:

`textTag = soup.find_all('div', {"class": re.compile(r'^storycontent$')})`

The result I wanna get is ONLY: `<div class="storycontent">`, but it also returns `<div class="storycontent ytstory">`

So, I am looking for a way to find an exact match (attribute class only contains *storycontent* and no other word or character).

Does anyone have any ideas? :-)

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516768/3832970).