# Webcrawler - Check if <a> tag with href is within an li tag using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm building a webcrawler in Python using beautiful soup to crawl wikipedia.  The problem is that wikipedia has a lot of garbage links that I don't want to look at.

#### For example:

target links with `#` before the target part

```html
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1">
  <a href="#Overview">
    <span class="tocnumber">1</span>
    <span class="toctext">Overview</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

talk pages

```html
<li class="nv-talk">
  <a href="/wiki/Template_talk:Data_structures" title="Template talk:Data structures">
    <span title="Discuss this template" style=";;background:none transparent;border:none;;">t</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

template pages

```html
<li class="nv-view">
  <a href="/wiki/Template:Data_structures" title="Template:Data structures">
    <span title="View this template" style=";;background:none transparent;border:none;;">v</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

and so on...

Now, I'm storing all the links I've already visited in a dictionary so I don't visit them twice, so I can avoid the **target links** by simply checking if the link up to the `#` symbol is already in the table.

I'm having a little more trouble with **talk, template, and other such pages**, however.

Something unique about them is that they always appear within an `<li>` tag, with some class attribute (`"nv-talk"`, `"nv-view"` etc), however my crawler relies on looking at the `<a>` tags, so I don't have access to the attributes of the `<li>` tag within which it is contained.

Furthermore, not all links on a page are contained within an `<li>` tag, so I can't simply search for `<li>` tags instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find_parents()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) method of BeautifulSoup. This will tell you if a particular tag is within another tag with specified attributes. In this case we are looking for an anchor tag within another tag with `nv-talk` or `nv-view` class attribute.

Demo:

```
html = '''<li class="nv-talk"><a href="/wiki/Template_talk:Data_structures" title="Template talk:Data structures"><span title="Discuss this    template" style=";;background:none    transparent;border:none;;">t</span></a></li>    '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
a_tag = soup.find('a')
a_tag.find_parents(attrs={'class':'nv-talk'})
```

which gives you:

```
[<li class="nv-talk"><a href="/wiki/Template_talk:Data_structures" title="Template talk:Data    structures"><span style=";;background:none transparent;border:none;;"    title="Discuss this template">t</span></a></li>]
```

For every anchor tag in the list of your urls, you can check if `find_parents()` returns an empty list. If yes, it means this link does not belong to a Talk or a Discuss page and hence safe for your crawling.

Another way to go about this problem would be to see if the `href` attribute of the anchor tag begins with 'http' or 'https'. But I am not entirely sure if it fits the logic of your code. What I mean by this is, anchor tags with `href` attributes that begin with `#` are links to sections within the same page. If you need to ignore these you can look for anchor tags that do not begin with `#` but instead begin with `http` or `https`. This is what I mean:

```
html = '''
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Overview"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Overview</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Overview</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Overview"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Overview</span></a></li>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
a_tag = soup.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(r'^http.*')})
```

This gives you only the link that begins with http.

Comment: It sounds like that might work.  What did you mean by using http vs https to solve the problem?  (I'm kinda new to html parsing)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it shortly.

Comment: @Kittenmittons Sure. Please accept the answer later if it addresses your question. Thanks.

Comment: will do. Ok so this works for li tags with class attribute. if I do something of the form: a_tag.find_parents(attrs={'class': re.compile('nv')}) ... how about if I want to look for multiple attributes?  Like also look for an id attribute  (one example would be <li id="pt-createaccount">.  Is there a way to search for multiple attributes in the same statement (I'm having trouble with the syntax), or should I simply put them in separate statements and 'or' them together?

Comment: @Kittenmittons This has info about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes