# Beautifulsoup find different sections while preserving order

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am looking to use beutifulsouop to extract text in the `span` section with a particular `class` value, and also the `div` section with a different `class` value while preserving order.

The following works with the exception that it does not preserve the order [i.e. the list has all of the `div` elements at the end, rather than when they occur in the page]

```
extract = soup.findAll('span', {"class": "value1"})  
extract += soup.findAll('div', {"class": "value2"})
```

Note - this is similar, but slightly different to the question - [BeautifulSoup findAll() given multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes) as i am specifically looking in `span` and `div` codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevents filtering out wrong tags. Extending the answer you mention:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div class="class1"></div><i class="class1"></i><span class="class2"></span><div class="class1"></div></body></html>')
for e in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["class1", "class2"]}):
    if e.name in ("div", "span"):
        print e
```

The filter can also be written as one-liner:

```
[e for e in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["class1", "class2"]}) if e.name in ("div", "span")]
```

BTW, even this can work:

```
 soup.findAll(["div", "span"], {"class":["class1", "class2"]})
```

See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-name-argument for the documentation on what can be the first argument to find all.