# Include multiple class names in findAll in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a line of code in a python script as shown below

```
for summaries in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cb-lv-scrs-col cb-font-12 cb-text-complete'}):
#do something with summaries
```

However, i want summaries to also include items from `div` items with another class called `cb-scag-mtch-status cb-text-inprogress`

I have tried the below as given here - [BeautifulSoup findAll() given multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes)

```
for summaries in soup.findAll('div',{'class':['cb-lv-scrs-col cb-font-12 cb-text-complete','cb-scag-mtch-status cb-text-inprogress']}):
#do something with summaries
```

but this is not working. What is the problem and how do i fix it?

Comment: The spaces between each class mean multiple classes, so in the first line you are searching for classes `cb-lv-scrs-col`, `cb-font-12`, and `cb-text-complete`.

Comment: I don't think so. In the source code, it was given  class="cb-lv-scrs-col cb-font-12 cb-text-complete"  So I think it means the whole class.

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned in that question as mentioned in my question above. It didn't work.

Comment: What about the regex solution? And it shouldn't matter if it didn't work, this is still a duplicate question and should be closed.

Comment: I prefer not using regex because that was the main aim of me writing the program. To scrape a web page without using regex.

Comment: I don't mean directly regex on the HTML. If you look at the second answer, it has `soup.findAll(True, {"class": re.compile("^(equal|up)$")})` which would find classes `equal` or `up`

Comment: I don't want to import any additional modules like re. So that solution would not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a simple [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div[class="cb-lv-scrs-col cb-font-12 cb-text-complete"],div[class="cb-scag-mtch-status cb-text-inprogress"]')
```

but, I doubt you really need or should check all of the classes present on an element, would not that be sufficient:

```
soup.select('div.cb-text-complete,div.cb-text-inprogress')
```

Comment: This can be used to find all the elements with the mentioned classes like `findAll` . I just checked. Thanks.