# How to use multiple condition findAll in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

ex) In html

```
<tr class='odd'> ~~~~ 
<tr class='even'> ~~~~
```

I am studying Crawling using Beautiful soup in python3.

I want to 'odd' class and 'even' class

So, I wrote that

```
url = 'http:// ~~~~'
src_code = requests.get(url)
plain_txt = src_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_txt, 'lxml')

trTag = soup.findAll('tr', class_ = 'odd' | 'even')
```

But,

```
trTag = soup.findAll('tr', class_ ='odd' | 'even')
```

in this line, error.

I want to find odd class and even class at one go.

Is it impossible?

I have to write 
    trTag = soup.findAll('tr',class_='odd')
    trTag = soup.findAll('tr',class_='even')

separately?

I want to learn.

Comment: Oh, I got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
trTag = soup.findAll('tr', class_ =['odd', 'even'])
```

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list)

If you pass in a list, Beautiful Soup will allow a string match against **any** item in that list.