# How to scrape news content and remove the irrelevant parts

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I aim to scrape the 100 news texts using BeautifulSoup and for-loop, and store the texts into the list **myarticle**. I expect **myarticle** should only contain the content of the news articles, which I find all have **h attribute**. However, the  result I got contain many irrelevant part, such as : "Thanks for contacting us. We've received your submission." and "This story has been shared 205,105 times.
205,105" and so on.

Another issue is, when I **print(myarticle[0])**, it gives me many news articles, but I expect it should only give me 1 article.

I would like to know how could I remove the irrelevant part and only keep the main content as we read from the news web. And how could I adjust the code so that when I **print(myarticle[0])**, it gives me the first news article.

One of the 100 news articles is on this page:
https://nypost.com/2020/04/21/missouri-sues-china-over-coronavirus-deceit/

Other news articles I want to scrape are on this site:
https://nypost.com/search/China+COVID-19/page/1/?orderby=relevance

Below are the lines of code relevant to my question.

```
            for pagelink in pagelinks:
                #get page text
                page = requests.get(pagelink)
                #parse with BeautifulSoup
                soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
                articletext = soup.find_all('p')
                for paragraph in articletext[:-1]:
                    #get the text only
                    text = paragraph.get_text()
                    paragraphtext.append(text)

                #combine all paragraphs into an article
                thearticle.append(paragraphtext)
    # join paragraphs to re-create the article            
    myarticle = [''.join(article) for article in thearticle]
    #show the first string of the list
    print(myarticle[0])
```

Comment: look at the source code and find a unique attribute on the element of the news you want.

Comment: What news website? If you share the link I could help you find a better find query.

Comment: This is the website :)
https://nypost.com/2020/04/21/missouri-sues-china-over-coronavirus-deceit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find_all('p')
```

Here you find all P tag elements in the webpage. P is very common tag used for most text, that is why you find non article text.

I would first find the containing div for just the article and then get the text, something like:

```
container = soup.find("div", class_=['entry-content', 'entry-content-read-more'])
articletext = container.find_all('p')
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but seems it doesn´t work.
I used: `containerr = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "entry-content entry-content-read-more"})
                articletext = containerr.find_all('p')`
I updated the question description by adding the website, it would be nice if you could further clarify your answer based on that specific website.
Thank you!

Comment: That is not how you search for multiple classes, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes Updated my example code.

Comment: container = soup.find() works, intead of container = soup.find_all() 
Thanks for the information about multiple classes! The text has two classes, which are 'entry-content', 'entry-content-read-more', am I right?

Comment: Yes, when ever a class has a space " " between the words it means it has multiple classes, you could search for both or just one of them. Prolly my mistake find() is probably good here. I dont have Beautifullsoup installed, so I am doing this from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will mark your answer and upvote it.
Could you help me solve another relevant question? I posted it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888917/how-to-scrape-web-news-and-combine-paragraphs-into-each-article