# How to scrape an element from a website which belongs to more than one class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape elements from a website.

`<h2 class="a b" data-test-search-result-header-title> Heading </h2>`

How can I extract the value Heading from the website using BeautifulSoup?

I have tried the following codes :

**Code 1 :**

`soup.find_all(h2,{'class':['a','b']})`

**Code 2:**

`soup.find_all(h2,class_='a b'})`

Both the codes return an empty list.
How to resolve this?

Comment: multiple class names will never get you the element. You some other way to look it up? besides class name?

Comment: In [a relevant thread](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/55015704.html), someone suggests using the CSS selector, as in `soup.select("h2.a.b")`.

Comment: `Code 1` gives me this element. But it gives also elements with `class="a"` and `class="b"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup findAll() given multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes)

Comment: @Prayson W. Daniel In that question the problem is to belong to any of the classes. In this case the element should belong to both the classes

Comment: Yes, but the thread discussion answers both questions. Let me know if none work and I will attempt to solve your issue.

Comment: @PravallikaMyneni : Updated my answer and added further information - Could you provide more code / a  minimal functional example, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix code2 to `soup.find_all('h2',class_='a b')`

**Example:**

Given are four `h2` tags with its classes, `soup.find_all('h2',class_='a b')` get the first of them, cause it is matching the filter.

To get the `text` of the `h2` element use `.text`, I have done it with

`[heading.text for heading in soup.find_all('h2',class_='a b')]`

cause we have to loop the `find_all()` result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h2 class="a b"> Heading a and b </h2>
<h2 class="b a"> Heading b and a </h2>
<h2 class="a"> Heading a </h2>
<h2 class="b"> Heading b </h2>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

[heading.text for heading in soup.find_all('h2',class_='a b')]
```

**Output**

```
[' Heading a and b ']
```

---

**Further thoughts**

You say, that it would not work for you - without providing further code/information, it is hard to help and more guessing. Let me show you what also could be a reason:

Let´s say you are scraping `google results`, there are a  lot of options to do that, I just wanna show two approaches `requests` and `selenium`.

**Requests Example**

Inspected classes for `h3` in browser are `LC20lb DKV0Md`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
headingsH3Class = soup.find_all('h3', class_='LC20lb DKV0Md')
headingsH3Only = soup.find_all('h3')

print(headingsH3Class[:2])
print(headingsH3Only[:2],'\n')
```

**Requests Example Output**

- An empty list

  []
- A list that show us that the inspected classes are not in the page content, we get back by requests

_

```
[<h3 class="zBAuLc"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">Stack Overflow</div></h3>, <h3 class="zBAuLc"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">Stack Overflow (Website) – Wikipedia</div></h3>]
```

**Selenium Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
headingsH3Class = soup.find_all('h3', class_='LC20lb DKV0Md')
headingsH3Only = soup.find_all('h3')

print(headingsH3Class[:2])
print(headingsH3Only[:2])
browser.close()
```

**Selenium Example Output**

- A List with exactly the `h3` with it´s both classes we searched for.

_

```
[<h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md"><span>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build ...</span></h3>, <h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md"><span>Stack Overflow (Website) – Wikipedia</span></h3>]
```

- A list with all `h3` Elements

_

```
[<h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md"><span>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build ...</span></h3>, <h3 class="r"><a class="l" data-ved="2ahUKEwj426uv9u3tAhUPohQKHYymBMAQjBAwAXoECAcQAQ" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions&amp;amp;ved=2ahUKEwj426uv9u3tAhUPohQKHYymBMAQjBAwAXoECAcQAQ">Questions</a></h3>]
```

**Conclusion**

Always check the data you are scraping, cause response and inspected things in browser can be different.

Comment: I have tried that. It is also returning an empty list

Comment: Could you provide an url of the website or a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: Wow, you went extra miles

Comment: Had a good day ;)  - It is something Q&A often do not contain in detail and that is a pity, but thx a lot that you saw and appreciated it.