# scraping python find return none but value exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website but my BeautifulSoup returns: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`. However, the element does exist.

Here is my code:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#time.sleep(60)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
NumArticle = url.split('/')[-2]
titreArticle = soup.find("h1", {"class":"wi-article-title article-title-main"}).get_text()
```

I used the: `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`
because otherwise I would get a 403 error.
And I tried to use a `time.sleep(x)` because I saw on a forum that it could solve the problem but in my case it didn't work.

Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies with the way you are searching for the two different classes. Try refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes) question.

```
soup.find('h1', class_=['wi-article-title', 'article-title-main'])
```

Comment: I also have the problem when I try to scrape a simple class like : 
```disclosures = soup.find("section", {"class": "sec"}).get_text() ```
But your solution for multiple classes seems to work.